# AngularJs and ngResource scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm learning angularjs and am having some trouble understanding how this concept works.

In a controller I have the following:

```
Customer.get({id: customer_id, action: 'edit', format : 'json'}, function(resource) {
  $scope.selected_customer = resource.customer;
  console.log($scope.selected_customer);
}, function(response) {
});
```

This works.  It retrieves the data from the server side ( i'm using rails ), and that console.log
shows what I would expect.

The concept i'm having trouble with is access to the $scope.selected_customer.

For example in this next case, the second log will not show the customer object I expect, but instead its an angular object that's a promise maybe? ( I'm using the unstable 1.1.4 fyi ).

```
test = Customer.get({id: customer_id, action: 'edit', format : 'json'}, function(resource) {
  $scope.selected_customer = resource.customer;
  console.log($scope.selected_customer);
}, function(response) {
});

// undefined
console.log($scope.selected_customer);
// angular object b{$resolved: false, $then: function, $get: function, $save: .... }
console.log(test);
```

So if I want a template to display information about this customer its not possible at this point.

Here's the full controller.  You can see I want to retrieve the object and then change the location 
which will be that of the template for editing this selected customer:

```
function CustomersEditController($scope, $location, Customer) {
  $scope.edit_customer = function(customer_id) {
    Customer.get({id: customer_id, action: 'edit', format : 'json'}, function(resource) {
      $scope.selected_customer = resource.customer;
      $location.path('/customers/' + customer_id_id + '/edit');
    }, function(response) {
      console.log('ERROR');
    });
  };
};
```

That works fine except for it doesn't populate the form with the selected_customers properties because of that scope issue.

Here's my service:

```
var customer_service = angular.module('customer_service', ['ngResource', 'ui']);

customer_service.factory('Customer', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/customers/:id/:action', {id: '@id'}, {
    update: { method: 'PUT' }
  });
});
```

My form is in a template ( using slim )

```
  div.center
    form(ng-submit='submit()' ng-controller='CustomersEditController')
      input(type='text' ng-model='selected_customer.first_name')
```

I am using the routeProvider:

```
angular.module('customer_app', ['customer_service'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($provider) {
    $provider.when('/:customer_id/edit/', { templateUrl: '/assets/customers/edit.html.slim', controller: 'CustomersController' });
  }])
  .config(["$httpProvider", function(provider) {
    provider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
  }]);
```

Here's my rails index page that gets the party started: 
Its just:

```
div(ng-app="customer_app")
  h1 Customers
    div(ng-view)
```

Any help or link to docs that maybe I missed ( or misunderstood ) would be awesome!

Comment: Where is the form and how do you populate it (how is it connected to the scope)?

Comment: I added the form in the main post.

Comment: Are you using `$routeProvider` and `ngView` at all? If so, can we see your Angular routes?

Comment: I updated the main post to show the route provider.  I have an ngView on my main rails index page.  I put that in above too.
The page renders, the location switches, and the form I want is displayed just how I need it to be except the text field is blank instead of showing the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the JavaScript you posted, your controller is `CustomersEditController`. But, when you switch URLs using `$location.path`, your `$routeProvider` loads up the new route, instantiating `CustomersController` instead (as defined via `$routeProvider`).

Whenver `$routeProvider` changes routes for you and creates an instance of a controller, your old controller goes away--so you're losing the data on `$scope` when you change URLs (the new controller gets its own scope).

To fix this, you can load up the user upon reaching the *new* controller:

```
function CustomersEditController($scope, $location) {
  $scope.edit_customer = function(customer_id) {
    $location.path('/customers/' + customer_id_id + '/edit');
  };
};

function CustomersController($scope, $location, $routeParams, Customer) {
  var customer_id = $routeParams.customer_id; // from $routeProvider
  Customer.get({id: customer_id, action: 'edit', format : 'json'}, function(resource) {
    $scope.selected_customer = resource.customer;
  }, function(response) {
    console.log('ERROR');
  });
};
```

Of course, in the case that the user ID is not valid, you'd have to display an error or redirect back to the previous URL.

Another option is to use the `resolve` property on your route configuration. Basically, `resolve` allows you to define data that the new controller is going to need, and you can ensure that said data is available before switching to the new route and inject the data into the new controller. By using a [promise](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q), you can use asynchronously loaded data, as well.

```
$routeProvider.when('/:customer_id/edit/', {
  templateUrl: '/assets/customers/edit.html.slim',
  controller: 'CustomersController',
  resolve: {
    customer: ['$q', '$route', 'Customer', function($q, $route, Customer) {
      var deferred = $q.defer()

      var customer_id = $route.current.params.customer_id;
      Customer.get({id: customer_id, action: 'edit', format : 'json'}, function(resource) {
        // got our user; change routes now
        deferred.resolve(resource.customer);
      }, function(response) {
        // Uh oh! No user found. Cancel changing routes
        // and trigger a $routeChangeError event
        deferred.reject(response);
      });

      // returning the promise ensures the route won't change
      // until the deferred that generated the promise is resolved
      return deferred.promise;
    }]
  }
});

// lower-case customer is injected based on name from `resolve` in route
function CustomersController($scope, $location, customer) {
  $scope.selected_customer = customer;
};
```

Comment: Thanks that was super helpful!  
Before trying this out I noticed that if I do an a(href='#/customers/{{customer.id}}/edit') and the provider routes to the editCustomerController The Customer.get works and populates the form if I do the $scope.selected_customer = resource.customer.  That var is still unavailable in other controller methods though.  Thanks again!